# Send API GET request with path variables in request-promise-native

Tags: node.js, get-request, request-promise

I want to do make the same api call as made in this postman photo below :
[postman](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RCXjmBx0HSZ3RJMj0JGrS_nNZCisNZAh/view?usp=sharing)

I have already tried the following code but it only returns some html not the desired response

```
async function vendor_info() {
    const options = {
        uri: 'http://**.**.**.**/vendor/:username/pj1527',
        json: true,
        method: 'GET'
    };

    let vendor_info = undefined;
    await requestPromise(options)
                        .then((body) => {
                            // err_token = 0;
                            vendor_info = body[0];
                            console.log(body);
                            // console.log(body[0]);
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            vendor_info = undefined;
                            // err_token = 1;
                            // console.log(err);
                        });

    return vendor_info;
}
```

**EDIT**

It's working now, actually the url should be 'http://**.**.**.**/vendor//pj1527' in the request.

Comment: What It return? What your desirable response?

Comment: @bcosta12 as the one shown in postman screenshot, it is linked with the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using async await then there is no need to use then and catch blocks, Try like this:

```
async function vendor_info() {
    try {
        const options = {
            uri: 'http://**.**.**.**/vendor/:username/pj1527',
            json: true,
            method: 'GET'
        };

        const vendor_info = await requestPromise(options);
        console.log('vendor_info: => ', vendor_info);
        return vendor_info;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error: => ', err);
        return err;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No it still returns some gibberish html.

Comment: i still think you don't need then and catch if you are using async/await, Did you tried the updated url with my code?